# Call an ajax function after every 10 sec, if success stop else proceed till success

Tags: ajax

I am tring to download a file, via ajax call. 
It should process every 20secs. 
If file present it will get downloaded and shall stop the futher ajax call, else same ajax should be processed till file is downloaded.
Below is what i have tried

```
 $.ajax({
                url: baseUrl + '/ajax/exportStudentInformation',
                data: {
                    'studentId' : studentId
                },
                type: "post",

                success: function(response) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        timeIntervalDownLoadFile = downloadFile(studentname); 
                    }, 60000);
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('There was error in processing csv file, please try again');
                }
            });

This is the function that needs to check if the file is present on the cloud and download it.

downloadFile: function(studentname) {

        $.ajax({
            url: baseUrl + '/ajax/downloadFile',
            data: {
                'studentname': studentname
            },
            'type': 'POST',
            error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
                alert('There was error in downloading file, please try again!!!');
            },
            abort: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                var message = "The file is being downloaded, please wait";
                $('#alertBar').html("<div class=\"alert alert-info\" >"+message+"<a class=\"close\">&times;</a></div>")
                $("#alertBar").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
                   $("#alertBar").slideUp(500);
                });
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.status) {
                    window.location.href = "https://urlwhereFileisStoredOnCloud/"+response.filename;
                } else {
                    var message = "File does not exist, please use export to generate file";
                    $('#alertBar').html("<div class=\"alert alert-danger\" >"+message+"<a class=\"close\">&times;</a></div>")
                    $("#alertBar").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
                       $("#alertBar").slideUp(500);
                    });
                    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#alertBar').offset().top }, 1000);
                }
            },
        }); 
    },
```

I have used set interval of jquery to call the second function time after delay. but it does not stops once the file download popup is shown. Any help will be apprciated.

Comment: You could have `let timeout = 0` and then `timeout = setTimeout(...)`. Then in your function, `clearTimeout(timeout)` on success.

Comment: yes i had tried that way, missed that section to add

Comment: File download popup is shown, but ajax calls still gets processed, does not stops

Comment: @ExplosionPills not sure, y it doesnot stop...